# Add Include statement (IASTPreprocessorIncludeStatement) using cdt

Tags: eclipse-cdt, abstract-syntax-tree

I want to add programmaticlly

1- Create header pragmatically maybe via CDTUITools or something relevant as there is class called `NewHeaderFileCreationWizardPage`, I tried it but with no luck

2- Add include statement `IASTPreprocessorIncludeStatement` node in ast tree, i.e "`#include headerFileName`" to certain AST, I can obtain the ast for a C code and Also I want to update the index of after insert this node in ast

Comment: What is it, specifically, from `NewHeaderFileCreationWizardPage` that you tried that didn't work?

Comment: We have existing CDT features that add include statements, like 'Add Include' and 'Organize Includes'. You can look at how they insert include statements. Relevant code is in `IncludeCreator.createEdit()`.

Comment: For updating the index, have a look at `IIndexManager.update()`. You can pass to it an array containing a single `ITranslationUnit` representing the file that has changed. The index manager can be obtained via `CCorePlugin.getIndexManager()`.